# Standard method for fetching the root and the intermediate certificates for SSL verification

Tags: python-3.x, docker, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I would like to verify the server certificate. The server certificate has been signed by the certificate chain (global sign root -> Alpha SSL) . I know that the package certifi can be used to fetch all the root certificates but this list does not comprise the intermediate AlphaSSL.

Thanks in advance for the help.

At the moment, I am working around it by manually downloading the certificate from Globalsign website but that does not seem to be the right way as it involves a manually process of downloading new certificate when the existing one expires.

Comment: The server MUST send the necessary intermediate(s), see [rfc8446 4.4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.4.2) or [rfc5246 7.4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2), so it should never be necessary to fetch them, although nowadays most PKI certs contain an AIA extension caIssuers field that allows you to do so if you wish, see [rfc5280 4.2.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1). Note however intermediates are usually longer lived than leaf/server certs, so a new server cert rarely means a new intermediate.

Comment: If you have OpenSSL installed, you can see the certificates served up in the chain by using something like `s_client -connect subdomain.name:433 -showcerts`.   What do you mean when you say verify?  Check that the intermediate points to a certificate in your machine's trust store, or you just want to confirm the value of the Issued to property is in a list of trusted CAs, or that the certificate is valid (within valid dates or was actually issued by the CA listed)?